# simple descriptive statistics in Rshiny as a table

Tags: r, shiny

I want to calculate simple statistics for all the variables in my dataset. Right now I display it with print, but want to display it as a table.

UI

```
mainPanel(
  h4("Summary of all covariates"),
  verbatimTextOutput('table')
)
```

server

```
myData <- reactive({
    data <- iris
    tab <- tableone::CreateTableOne(data = data)
    summary(tab)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderPrint(
    myData()
    )
```

I don't now how to convert `summary(tab)` to table in the above ui code

`Iris` dataset here is for illustration only. While my dataset has around 30 variables, both numerical and categorical

Answer (score 0):

You can use `capture.output`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tableone)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    h4("Summary of all covariates"),
    verbatimTextOutput('table')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  myData <- reactive({
    dat <- iris
    CreateTableOne(data = dat)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderText({
    paste(capture.output(summary(myData())), collapse = "\n")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```